# Receive Custom Notification iOS swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, swift2

I tried to receive my custom notification from my web through parse website.

Code didReceiveRemoteNotification :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
         PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)}
```

Here is the JSON i received from parse website :

```
 [aps: {
     alert = "test adirax";
     sound = default; }]
```

It works well for me and the notification shows up. However when i tried to push data from my website, the notification can't shows/ pop up.

Here is my JSON looks like :

```
{"aps": {"alerts" : "test", 
         "links": "",
         "sounds": "default"}}
```

I tried to print(userInfo) and the result is i get all the data like above, but there is no notif.

I guess I'm missing some code to convert the data ?

**INFORMATION**

For the specific information, i tried receive notification from parse.com through subscribe "channels". so it's not a local notification or else.

**ADD** Code Added (according to my JSON type)

```
  if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
            let userInfo = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
            let aps = userInfo!["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
            let alert1 = aps!["alerts"] as? String
            let link1 = aps!["links"] as? String
        }
```

And this :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
        let alert1 = aps!["alerts"] as? String
        let link1 = aps!["links"] as? String
        print(userInfo)
        print("success")
    }
```

When i debugged one by one, its success i collect all the data, however i still missing the notification showed up ?

**SOLVED PART 1** 
So far i managed to get the data and push the notification out, but it's only when i open the application. Code :

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }

    let notifiAlert = UIAlertView()

    let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
        let alert1 = aps!["alerts"] as? String
        let link1 = aps!["links"] as? String

        notifiAlert.title = alert1!
        notifiAlert.message = link1
        notifiAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        notifiAlert.show()

        print(userInfo)
        print("success")

}
```

I use a local notification trick, but how to pop up the notification when i'm not using the app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add custom informations like this:

```
{"aps": {"alerts" : "test", 
         "sound": "default"},
 "name": "Steven",
 "age": "32"
}
```

And parse it like this:

```
let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
let msg = aps!["alert"] as? String
let name = userInfo["name"] as? String
print(name)
```

**EDIT:**
You have to check push notification on two functions of `UIApplicationDelegate`

First.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // check for push message
        if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
            let userInfo = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
            let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
            let msg = aps!["alert"] as? String
            let name = userInfo["name"] as? String
            print(name)
        }
}
```

Second.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject]
    let msg = aps!["alert"] as? String
    let name = userInfo["name"] as? String
    print(name)
}
```

Comment: where should i add custom information to ?  and if i add custom information, will my data be replace by this data ? example like : My web JSON is "Steven", and it will be replace by "test" ??

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can add your custom information like that. @Steventan

Comment: ok but i have a question, i don't have "name" and "age", i can just don't use that data right ? ( According to my JSON ) @Soohwan Park

Comment: You don't have to add "name" and "age". You can add your custom data what ever you need and You can remove it from the JSON or you can simply ignore them from ios. @Steventan

Comment: yes i've done that, thanks to you now i can retrieve the Json data. however i still missing the notification showed up. i've update my page @Soohwan Park

Comment: change "sounds" to "sound" in "aps". And IOS notification is not shows up when the application is in foreground. @Steventan

Comment: Ok gonna try it, 1 question This function i have to put inside `if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {}` or i can just leave it like that ? (on my top post)

Comment: I don't know what is `PFPush` and `PFAnalytics`. but I think it wants to check if the app is opened by touching notification or not. I think if you want check push notification touch rate on `PARSE website`, leave it. @Steventan

Comment: i've updated some information. please look at it,  also thanks it works fine. @Soohwan Park

Comment: When the app is in foreground, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called immediately.

When the app is in background, Notification is shows up on the notification center and If the user clicks the notification from the notification center, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called and the app become foreground.

When the app is terminated by `double home->swipe the app`, the notification is shows up on the notification center and If user clicks the notification, the application is launched and the the notification data comes to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. @Steventan

Comment: So basically i have to put the code inside ApplicationState too ?

Comment: i got it, it only works for opening the application, how if my data contain link to website ? does it still work normally ? 
like when i press the notification it will auto-direct to the website : Https://example.com. ??

Comment: No. that's not possible. You have to do it on your own in your application. @Steventan

Comment: Gonna try it, Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You should add your custom data to the top-level of your payload, not to the `aps` object.

Like this, for instance:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alerts" : "test", 
        "sounds": "default"
    },
    "links": "",
}
```

Comment: but the JSON i received is dynamic depend of what i send through my website. if i set at the top of my playload, it will become static right ?

Comment: @Steventan how could it become static? It's part of your payload.

Comment: Updated answer to illustrate the structure of the payload.

Comment: if i put my "links" inside "aps" will it be wrong ? 
Or its still working but with wrong structure ?

Comment: I would have thought it would not cause any issues, but since you're apparently having some with this incorrect structure, just stick to having your extra information in the right place, outside of `aps`. `aps` should be reserved for data that is used internally by iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the information ,will be noted if something error occur to me later. Thanks!