# Remote notification category not being sent to client device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-ruby

I am using Amazon SNS to provide remote notifications for my iOS app and I am having trouble getting notification categories to be included when received on the client device.

Here's how I posting the notification from the server using SNS:

```
@client = Aws::SNS::Client.new(...)

resp = @client.publish({
    target_arn: endpoint_arn,
    message: {
        default: body,
        APNS: {
            aps: {
                alert: {
                    title: title,
                    body: body
                },
                category: category
            }
        }
    }.to_json,
    subject: title,
    message_structure: "json"
})
```

And on the iOS device I receive the notification in the app delegate with:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * aps = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    if (aps) {
        NSString * category = [aps objectForKey:@"category"];
        NSLog(@"Category is: %@", category); // Category is: nil
    } else {
        NSLog(@"APS dictionary nil");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the category is always nil. I've tried a few different structures of the `aps` object, but I can't seem to get the category on the iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Is a little late but may help somebody else.

Try sending `category` property at the same level of `aps` like this:

```
resp = @client.publish({
    target_arn: endpoint_arn,
    message: {
        default: body,
        APNS: {
            aps: {
                alert: {
                    title: title,
                    body: body
                }
            },
            category: category
        }
    }.to_json,
    subject: title,
    message_structure: "json"
})
```

And get the response with

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSString * category = [userInfo objectForKey:@"category"];
    NSLog(@"Category is: %@", category);        
}
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34507291/4848308) for more information.

Hope this help ;)